# Prevent automated account creation without using CAPTCHA

Tags: denial-of-service, e-commerce

I had a scenario, where someone created thousands of user accounts in a shop system, which flooded the DB.
Different usernames/emails were used and each creation came from a different IP address.

How can someone prevent / avoid such an "attack"?

Is there anything else besides CAPTCHAS that a programmer can do?

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you against the use of a captcha?

Comment: Only collect most account details once you've verified the email address? It won't stop a really determined attacker, but adds an extra barrier to most attackers.

Comment: @Ryan Entering distorted letters and identifying street signs has a fairly notable impact on usability.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that a 'developer' could do to avoid bulk account creation in this manner - but it will depend on the appetite / budget for a client.

For example, a number of commercial WAFs are likely to spot the patterns in the end and start blocking these - even when they are coming from differing IPs.  The WAF, if it uses cloud based learning / definitions, may have already seen issues from those IPs for other sites that it is being used to protect.

If you're just looking for a purely 'programmed' solution - then many have attempted to develop their own versions of CAPTCHA (sometimes you see things as simple as answer the question of 5+3 = X in a form field), but the reality is that it is going to take a lot of time / effort / expense to develop anything robust enough.

Why does the client in this case not want to use CAPTCHA?

Comment: I guess because having account creation as easy as possible. if there is no programmatic solution, we need to use captchas anyway